# synch problem with chrony and xenomai

Tags: synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I've just discovered that to synchronize messages across different physical machines I have to use Chrony. Everithing is fine....except when I actually run my real robot, which is actuated with the xenomai module. Since then, the clock starts delaying very quickly. As soon as I stop the task, the clock starts re-synch. Note that the daemon is active all the time.

I think that xenomai is kind of excluding chrony o something like that, I'm not familiar with RT-linux unfortunately

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167401/synch-problem-with-chrony-and-xenomai/) by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After painfull procedures...I solved the problem.

I recompiled the kernel with the `CONFIG_HZ = 100` and that solved the problem for me.

Hope that it helps.

---

Originally posted by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) with karma: 275 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0